# How to re-enable Win 10 hypervisor after Android Studio 3 disabled it

Tags: android-studio, hyper-v

During the emulator setup to run a project it informed me that Hyper-V needed to be turned off.  The wording led me to believe that I would have to do that myself, instead the software took it upon itself to do so and now I cannot figure out how to re-enable the hypervisor.  Docker is howling at the moon and in 'Turn Windows Features On and Off' all of the selections for Hyper-V are checked.

I've tried deselecting those, rebooting, re-selecting them and rebooting again to no avail.  The one other post I could find regarding this came with a non answer to the question so is of no use to me. I've also tried re-enabling from Powershell but that also did nothing.

Virtualization is enabled in the BIOS as I had Hyper-V and Docker running before this incident.

Does anyone know how to fix this issue?  I am aware of the Visual Studio Tools for Xamarin that has an emulator that works but again, I need Hyper-V up and running.

Comment: are you using   virtmgmt.msc   to look at your HyperV status   that command will bring up the hyper v manager which may be a different view for you.  That will be more obvious about the running state of the service.

Comment: @SqlSurfer After  some more research using different search terms I came across [this](https://superuser.com/questions/858259/hyper-v-reports-that-the-hypervisor-is-not-running-how-to-start-the-hypervisor/1160635) post. After uninstalling both Android Studio and Intel HAXM (which was the offending party) I discovered that the hypervisor process still wasn't running. Using `bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype auto` reset it to run at boot. A quick reboot and all seems to be well.